# Possible to "listen" to a CSS value for a DOM element and tell another DOM element to match it?

Tags: javascript, css, drupal

I'm trying to hack Drupal's colorpicker module so that as my user drags it around picking colors, he sees colors changing on the web site's  in real-time.

Right now the colorpicker's js changes the color of the picker widget in real-time.

I want to hack the js so that the color of the picker widget AND a specific DOM element change background colors at once.

Is there a way I can write some code that "listens" to the background-color setting of the colorpicker input and then changes the background-color of ?

Here's the code where Drupal is applying settings from the colorpicker widget to its input:

```
Drupal.behaviors.colorpicker = function(context) {  
$("input.colorpicker_textfield:not(.colorpicker-processed)", context).each(function() {
var index = $('body').find('input.colorpicker_textfield').index($(this));
Drupal.colorpickers[index] = new Drupal.colorpicker($(this).addClass('colorpicker-processed'));
Drupal.colorpickers[index].init();
});
```

What can I add to this to tell it to "listen" to the background color of "input.colorpicker_textfield" and then set that value to "body" in real time as it changes?

Answer (score 1):

Try using change() to apply it to the bg.

```
$("input").change( function () {
   //var below would obviously have to be correctly formatted.
   var newColor$(this).val();
   $(body).css({background-color: newColor});
});
```

Comment: I tried clearning it up some: $("input").change( function () {
   //var below would obviously have to be correctly formatted.
   var newColor = $(this).val();
   $("body").css({"background-color", newColor});

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Cole's answer with some improvements (assuming '#' is not included by the colorpicker):

```
$('input.colorpicker_textfield').live('change', function() {
    var color = this.value;
    if(color.search((/^[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}/) != -1) {
        body.style.backgroundColor = '#'+this.value;
    }
});
```

- Uses more specific selector
- uses the 'live' event handling method, ensuring the handler will be attached to any dynamically created colorpickers
- It will not change the background color if the input is not a hex value
- It uses the style attribute directly instead of wrapping in the jQuery object.